# Is it better to use async HTTP client in a tomcat servlet routine?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, asynchronous, threadpool

People commonly believe that asynchronized IO operations (such as HTTP calls via async client implementation) are superior than synchronous counterparts in terms of system scalability and resource usage.

I am developing a classic Java web application, it uses conventional servlet and runs in Tomcat. There is a request processing routine which looks like:

```
doPost() {
    // make HTTP call to remote host
    // upon completion of the HTTP call, return success
}
```

There is a choice: to make the HTTP call, I may choose to use a conventional blocking HTTP client library (such as `Apache HTTPClient`) or a non-blocking asynchronous HTTP client (such as `Apache AsyncHTTPClient`).

In this scenario, is there any advantage of using asynchronous HTTP client implementation? I am in disbelief:

- The `doPost()` must wait for the HTTP call response, therefore using asynchronous HTTP client does not improve responsiveness.
- Tomcat starts a thread pool for processing requests. The `doPost()` routine must block at the HTTP call and therefore using asynchronous HTTP client does not decrease the total number of JVM threads.

Are my thoughts valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMMO your thoughts are perfectly valid. Async is no magic, in your scenario you need to wait to external resource to respond to the servlet client, i see no benefit in use AsyncHttpClient. Probably in other circumstances there is and advantage of the async solution, for example:

- Your client application is async too, you receive the request call async http and immediately returns the control to your client. When you really receive the answer from the external resource you need to communicate with your client via comet or websockets. This way your server its never blocked and the scalability its better, but probably its a huge change in your architecture and you need to be sure that you really need to make a change like this. And off course this systems has other problems.
- You have more than one call to external resources, in this scenario make async calls and then waits before return to your client for the completion of the various external resources its clearly a big improvement.

Only one more thing, remember ALWAYS put a timeout in a call to external resources, probably your are aware of this, but i learn this the hard way in the past.